# How to parse XML file with namespaces in Java?

Tags: java, xml

Am relatively new to java and trying to parse an XML that has prefix in Java.
sample.

```
    <client:ClientName>
        <client:nameTitle>Mr</client:nameTitle>
        <client:familyName>John</client:familyName>
        <client:givenName>George</client:givenName>
    </client:ClientName>
```

while I have got many solutions that can read tags without the prefixes such as using the getTagValue in content such as

```
    <client>Content</client>.
```

retrieving tag values as shown before has proved challenging. Any assistance offered is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct terminology is "XML namespaces"; I have updated the title. That should result in *many* good reads online...

Comment: Maybe add some code so that we know what library you intend to use at least. A code resulting in error or unexpected result is also better than no code.

Comment: found a solution; it's not very elegant but works for related xml file. http://www.coderanch.com/t/445366/java/java/java-Xpath-Namespace-Resolved. Apologies for not adding the code.. thnx @pst. still looking for something less clustered.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is not *namespace well-formed*. It uses a namespace prefix, 'client', without declaring a binding for that prefix: one would expect to see `xmlns:client="something"`.

In principle XML that is not namespace well-formed is still XML, and there are ways of processing it; but it rarely encountered and most XML tools these days are designed to handle only namespace-well-formed input.

The answer to your question depends on knowing whether you really want to process XML that is not namespace-well-formed, or whether you've simply omitted the namespace declaration from your sample.